Story about Jesus being kidnapped by the church
I remember very little about this book (actually, I do remember pieces, but I know that I tend to misremember and mix books up that I read, so I will omit the details that might lead you down a wrong path). It had a very interesting concept:
There was a male protagonist who was somehow involved in the world ending and wanted to save it. The world ending had to do with an evil being being imprisoned by the church, about to break free and end the world. The twist was that it turned out that the church, to consolidate their power, had kidnapped Jesus. They had held him for 2000 years, to keep him from interfering in their power grab with his messages of love and peace. Now, after 2000 years of imprisonment, he was pissed and wanted to end it all once he could escape his captors.
I do not remember how it ended. It wasn't comedy; it wasn't much of a social study or church criticism; it was just a "world ends in apocalypse if we don't do something" story like many of the books I read at that time. Apocalypses changed, but that was a trending topic after the Cold War was declared over and "the Russians!" didn't make good stories any more.
I read it in the late 90s or early 2000s. It may have been from the local library, so it might not have been new then, but I don't remember it officially playing in the past or future. It was kind of today-ish then.
The book was not short; it was novel-sized, maybe 300+ pages. It wasn't part of a series. But I might misremember; maybe it was a collection of different stories in one book.
I don't remember any names or other characters, and I don't remember the ending.
I thought it was Hohlbein; I read a lot of him in those years, but I could not find it.

I have not read the book in question, but since you mentioned Wolfgang Hohlbein this is probably "Der Widersacher" (Bastei-Lübbe 1995). This would translate to "The Adversary", in the sense of somebody standing in the way of the completion of God's will.
From an amazon.de reader review:

Geradlinig und recht spannen erzählt Hohlbein eine originelle Version
des Jesus-Stoffes. Ein Versicherungsmakler wird zufällig in den
Kleinkrieg einer Gruppe palästinensischer Terroristen gegen
amerikanische Sicherheitskräfte verwickelt. Dabei wird als
Kollateralschaden ein altes Kloster zerstört. Dort wurde seit 2000
Jahren Jesus gefangen gehalten, der schon von den Jüngern festgesetzt
wurde, um damit das Jüngste Gericht heraus zu zögern, um damit der
Menschheit Gelegenheit zu geben sich zu bessern. Bis fast zum Schluss
meint der Leser, dass es sich bei dem "Widersacher" um Satan
persönlich handelt. Einige nette Details peppen die Geschichte noch
auf, z.B. dass die von Jesus wieder erweckten Toten von Ami-Soldaten
für Zombies gehalten und erschossen werden. Glücklicherweise
verzichtet Hohlbein auf die sonst bei ihm übliche Vater/Sohn (oder
Tochter) Geschichte. Dies alles lässt über einige logische Brüche
hinwegsehen, ohne die Hohlbein anscheinend nicht auskommt.

Which Google translates to

Hohlbein tells an original version of the Jesus story in a
straightforward and tense way. An insurance broker accidentally
becomes involved in a group of Palestinian terrorists' small war
against American security forces. An old monastery is destroyed as
collateral damage. Jesus has been imprisoned there for 2000 years,
having already been imprisoned by the disciples in order to delay the
Last Judgment in order to give humanity the opportunity to improve.
Until almost the end, the reader thinks that the “adversary” is Satan
himself. Some nice details spice up the story, for example that the
dead who were raised by Jesus are mistaken for zombies by American
soldiers and are shot. Fortunately, Hohlbein avoids the usual
father/son (or daughter) story. All of this makes it possible to
overlook some logical breaks that Hohlbein apparently cannot do
without.

That sounds like a match. Found it by scanning Wikipedia for likely sounding titles, the book is not listed in Hohlbeins list of works in the isfdb database for some reason. The review above is quite favorable, most Goodreads reviews seem to hate the book.
